# Java - jxls - XLSTransformer thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, jxls

If I need to call a method that creates an `xls` file from multiple threads - can I use `XLSTransformer` as `synchronized` (or even not) field of the class? And if `XLSTransformer.transformXLS()` method really expensive, or it's OK to create a new instance any time I need to create `xls`?

That's what I'm talking about:

```
private synchronized XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();

public void createXls() {
    //...
    transformer.transformXLS("template.xls", beans, "result.xls");
}
```

Won't it break if I call `createXls()` from multiple threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single note, that `XLSTransformer` is thread-safe, so you can assume it is not, or analyze jXLS source code ([link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jxls/jxls-core/1.0.6/net/sf/jxls/transformer/XLSTransformer.java#XLSTransformer.transformXLS%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.util.Map%2Cjava.lang.String%29)). However, be informed, that it can be different in each lib version and you should check again after each update.

If it is about your example, the `synchronized` keyword is illegal modifier for fields. You can use it with methods to lock on `this` object:

```
public synchronized void createXls() {
    //...
}
```

or with blocks when you can choose object treated as lock:

```
public void createXls() {
    //...
    synchronized( transformer ) { 
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

More information in Java tutorials:

1. [Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)
2. [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)